# Wireless is hard blocked

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless, realtek-wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I am using HP Pavilion 15 PC. I dual booted my PC with Ubuntu 16.04; and 
had windows 10 previously installed on my device.

The wireless report (latest - after edit mentioned below) :
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vq99YSfb6R/

My wifi is not working. It does work on windows but when I switch to Ubuntu it stops working. The key (f12) which switches between on/off aeroplane mode, is red (aeroplane mode on) while booting but turns white( aeroplane mode off) when windows is turned on, making the wifi work properly in windows. But in ubuntu, the key remains red. And you can't switch it however times you press.

When run

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

this is what I get

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

everytime I boot I have to run

```
sudo ifconfig wlo1 up
```

for which, the

```
sudo rfkill list all
```

leads to

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Also, the Network window, shows an airplane mode slider which is in default on but gets shifted to off; but the wireless slider remains at off, however times I try to slide it on.

My wireless is RT3290.

Edit: I tried this

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rt2800pci
echo "blacklist rt2800pci"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

But now I can't even find wireless network to enable anywhere.

Also here is the wireless report again:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/vq99YSfb6R/

Please help anyone! 
Thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: Can anyone please help?